# Pgfkeys associated with macros lead to unexpected results

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, key-value, pgfopts

Consider the following class:

```
% CLASS

% Preamble
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2022/10/11]
\LoadClass[varwidth]{standalone}
\makeatletter

% Pgfoptions
\RequirePackage{pgfopts}
\pgfkeys{
    /myclass/.cd,
    optionA/.store in = \myclass@optionA,
    optionA = ,
    optionB/.store in = \myclass@optionB,
    optionB = \myclass@optionA,
}
\ProcessPgfOptions{/myclass}

\newcommand{\setA}[1]{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/myclass/optionA}{#1}\texttt{setA(#1)}\\}
\newcommand{\setB}[1]{\pgfkeyssetvalue{/myclass/optionB}{#1}\texttt{setB(#1)}\\}
\newcommand{\defineA}[1]{\pgfkeys{/myclass/optionA = #1}\texttt{defineA(#1)}\\}
\newcommand{\defineB}[1]{\pgfkeys{/myclass/optionB = #1}\texttt{defineB(#1)}\\}

\newcommand{\printoptions}{\fbox{\texttt{%
    [A = (\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionA}, \myclass@optionA)]% 
    [B = (\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionB}, \myclass@optionB)]
}}\\}
\makeatother
```

used in the code:

```
\documentclass[optionA = A0]{myclass}
\begin{document}
\printoptions % => [A = (, A0)] [B = (, A0)]
\setA{A1}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A0)] [B = (, A0)]
\defineA{A2}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A2)] [B = (, A2)]
\setB{B1}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A2)] [B = (B1, A2)]
\defineB{B2}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A2)] [B = (B1, A2)]
\end{document}
```

---

There are many things I do not understand:

**QUESTION 0:** Why does `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/myclass/optionX}{#1}` and `\pgfkeys{/myclass/optionX = #1}` lead to different results?

**QUESTION 1:** Why printing `\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionX}` and `\myclass@optionX` lead to different results while I would expect the `.store in` to make the two equivalent?

**QUESTION 2:** Why `defineA(A2)` change also the value of `\myclass@optionB`? I would have expected the `optionB = \myclass@optionA` during the definition of `pgfkeys` to just be an initialization instead of having a permanent link between the two.

**QUESTION 3:** Is there a way to define the `pgfkeys` to that `\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionX}` and `\myclass@optionX` are synonymous always correspond to the same value, including for example a change through `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/myclass/optionX}` or a `\pgfkeys{/myclass/optionX = XN}`?

**QUESTION 4:** How to initialize the `pgfkeys` so that `optionB = \myclass@optionA` only initialize `\myclass@optionB` with the value of `\myclass@optionA` (but if `\myclass@optionA` is changed later, it does not change the value given by `\myclass@optionB`) as in:

```
\printoptions % => [A = (, A0)] [B = (, A0)]
\setA{A1}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A0)] [B = (, A0)]
\defineA{A2}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A2)] [B = (, A0)] % Difference here: B stays the same!!!!
\setB{B1}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A2)] [B = (B1, A0)]
\defineB{B2}
\printoptions % => [A = (A1, A2)] [B = (B1, A0)]
```

More generally, I think I am missing the big picture of what is going behind the association of `pgfkeys` and `macros`, so any big picture explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: On the Questions 2 and 4: You're (behind the scenes) doing something like `\def\myclass@optionB{\myclass@optionA}` without any expansion, so if you now change the meaning of `\myclass@optionA` the `\myclass@optionB` will expand (in two steps) to that new meaning. You can use `optionB/.expand once=\myclass@optionA` to get the behaviour you're after.

Comment: The `.store in` just does that. Store the value in the given macro. It *does not* store it in the value of the key. Your `\pkgfkeysvalueof`s will just expand to `\relax` if it's value isn't set (either via `\pgfkeyssetvalue` or `<key>/.initial=` or `<key>=` once the key has been initialized with `.initial`. Don't mix the two (and I'd argue `.store in` is unnecessary if we already have value-keys).

Comment: Q3: `\def\myclass@optionX{\pgfkeysvalueof{/myclass/optionX}}` (but one more expansion!) and forget about `.store in`. On the fly you can do [`\pgfkeysgetvalue{/myclass/optionX}\myclass@optionX`](https://tikz.dev/pgfkeys#\pgfkeysgetvalue) which might be easier to deal with and doesn't need another expansion.

Comment: @Skillmon I meant one more than `\pgfkeysvalueof`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attempts to be the "big picture" answer, even though this answer just focuses on a single aspect of `pgfkeys`, namely how to store values given to keys for later use: `.store in` and `\pgfkeyssetvalue`/`.initial`.

In general `pgfkeys` has two ways to store values:

1. Storing the value inside the key path
2. Storing the value in some macro

You can achieve the first by using the `.initial` handler to define the key (`\pgfkeys{/foo/.initial = 1}`), and then access the value by using `\pgfkeysvalueof` or `\pgfkeysgetvalue`. This simply hides the macro in a non-obvious name and adds a level of indirection, the advantage being that the same name to set the key is used to get its value, instead of another macro name.

The second is what `.store in` sets up, so `\pgfkeys{/foo/.store in = \foo}`. This sets things up such that each time the key is set the definition of `\foo` is changed to expand to the given value. The advantage is that you get more control over where stuff is stored, and have an easier life expanding it. The drawback is yet another name for the same thing.

When you use `\pgfkeyssetvalue{/foo}{bar}` you're only assigning to the first storage, you don't call the code that was set up by the `.store in` handler, so the assignment is not made to `\foo`, but only to the key path `/foo`.

Which of the two you prefer (and which is to be preferred) isn't dictated, `pgfkeys` gives this choice to the user. And while this choice *per se* isn't something bad, it sometimes (like in your case), leads to confusion. I'd advice to select one of the mechanisms and stick to it for one project (that doesn't mean another project by the same author can't use the other approach).

Personally I'd prefer the second approach, as I don't see the gain of that level of indirection (and my own key=value implementation -- *advertisement block:* `expkv` -- doesn't support the other). Others (like [@Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/663260/pgfkeys-associated-with-macros-lead-to-unexpected-results#comment1649757_663260)) prefer the first approach.