PGF keys are setting individually but not as a key list
Using the TeX Works AppImage with a local installation of TeX Live (texlive-full, 2021.20220204-1), I'm having trouble getting "pgfkeys" to work with a key list.  Setting each key individually does work, but that will be untenable in the long run.  I've stripped everything down to a MWE, tried it with both pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX using the Article and Memoir classes, and stared for awhile at the examples in the TikZ/PGF manual, but if there's something I mistyped I'm not spotting it.
Current progress:  Decided to uninstall distro's texlive-full and replace with TUG's latest, hoping the issue will resolve itself.  Installing the latter now.
Update:  No change.  Still not certain whether it's a bug, or me just doing it wrong.
(Question originally posted to Stack Overflow, now moved here.)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}

% These work...
%   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/John Smith/inches}{68}
%   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/John Smith/pounds}{145}

% This doesn't...
    \pgfkeys{
        /John Smith/inches=68,
        /John Smith/pounds=145,
    }

    \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/inches}
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/pounds}

\end{document}

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999993 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=xelatex)  restricted \write18 enabled. entering extended mode (./MWE.tex LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2022-01-21> (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t ex))) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def (|extractbb --version)) No file MWE.aux. (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)

Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/John Smith/inches', to which y ou passed '68', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation. Type  H <return>  for immediate help.  ...

l.13 ^^I}

H This error message was generated by an \errmessage command, so I can't give any explicit help. Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues, and deduce the truth by order and method.

? Process interrupted by user


You need to tell pgfkeys what the key is before you set it. That is, you have to define it first or use a handler.

Related, though also pretty much contained in the nice answer below by @cfr: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692450/117050

You can't use an undefined key as if it is already defined. So either you have to define them individually first or you need to use a key handler. For example,
  \pgfkeys{
    /John Smith/inches/.initial=68,
    /John Smith/pounds/.initial=145,
  }

Alternatively, you could define the keys to store the values in macros. For example,
  \pgfkeys{%
    /John Smith/.cd,
    inches/.store in=\jsinches,
    pounds/.store in=\jspounds,
    inches=12,
    pounds=sterling,
  }
  \jsinches{} \jspounds{}

Complete code for examples:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
  
  % These work...
  %   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/John Smith/inches}{68}
  %   \pgfkeyssetvalue{/John Smith/pounds}{145}
  
  % This works too ...
  \pgfkeys{
    /John Smith/inches/.initial=68,
    /John Smith/pounds/.initial=145,
  }
  
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/inches}
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/pounds}

  \pgfkeys{%
    /John Smith/.cd,
    inches/.store in=\jsinches,
    pounds/.store in=\jspounds,
    inches=12,
    pounds=sterling,
  }
  \jsinches{} \jspounds{}
  
\end{document}

pgfkeys predefines a variety of handlers and others are defined by libraries and packages.
Moreover, unlike l3keys, which is part of LaTeX, pgfkeys also allows you to define custom key handlers. For example, chronos includes the following definition,
  /handlers/.chronos dimen/.code={%
    \pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}{%
      \pgfmathparse{##1}%
      #1=\pgfmathresult pt
    }%
    \pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath'}{#1=##1}%
    \pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath'+}{\advance #1 by ##1}%
    \pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath'-}{\advance #1 by -##1}%
    \pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath+}{%
      \pgfmathparse{##1}%
      \advance #1 by \pgfmathresult pt
    }%
    \pgfkeysdef{\pgfkeyscurrentpath-}{%
      \pgfmathparse{##1}%
      \advance #1 by -\pgfmathresult pt
    }%
  },

This creates a handler which allows me to create a sub-family of keys all at once. For instance,
timeline margin/.chronos dimen=\chronos@timelinemargin,

This creates not only timeline margin, but also timeline margin', timeline margin+, timeline margin'+ and so on, all of which set or the target dimension.
EDIT
How about something like this?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}

\begin{document}
  \pgfkeys{%
    /handlers/.new person/.code={%
      \edef\tempa{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
      \edef\tempb{\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
      \pgfqkeys{\tempa}{%
        name/.initial=name,
        height/.initial=height,
        role/.initial=role,
      }%
    },
    /John Smith/.new person,
    /John Smith/.cd,
    name=John smith,
    height=3cm,
    role=Mr. Small,
  }
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/name}
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/height}
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/role}
\end{document}

So the idea would be to provide an interface such as this:
\NewPerson{<name of person>}{<list of key-values>}

which could be configured using code such as this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{%
  /handlers/.new person/.code={%
    \edef\tempa{\pgfkeyscurrentpath}%
    \edef\tempb{\pgfkeyscurrentname}%
    \pgfqkeys{\tempa}{%
      name/.initial=name,
      height/.initial=height,
      role/.initial=role,
    }%
  },
}
\NewDocumentCommand \NewPerson { m +m }
% \NewPerson{<Name of Person>}{<list of key-values>}
{%
  \pgfkeys{%
    /#1/.new person,
    /#1/.cd,
    name={#1},
    #2,
  }%
}
\begin{document}
  \NewPerson{John Smith}{%
    height=3cm,
    role=Mr. Small,
  }
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/name}
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/height}
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/John Smith/role}
\end{document}


I have dozens of variables (height, weight, sex, etc.) that I would like to apply to hundreds of entries (John, Sue, Bob, etc.) via pgfqkeys{/[person]}{/[variable]=[value]} in each person's file.  Can I create one "master" pgfqkeys that initializes everything using a wildcard for the person's name, then use individual pgfqkeys in each person's file to set their particular values?  Or am I barking up the wrong tree with pgf?

@user182238 You can use keys to create keys. You can use handlers to create keys. You could even set things up so that you didn't need to pre-create the key. But that leads me to wonder whether keys are really the best option here. Why not custom macros, say? Why do this with pgfkeys particularly? To put this another way: what are you doing with the information stored in the keys afterwards?

Though I guess it wouldn't be much trouble to simply append the ".initial" to each person's list.  As long as I can use pgfqkeys to get around having to paste the name over and over.

I've done custom tokens and commands -- not sure if that's different from macros -- and decided it would be a lot easier (Ha!) to be able to use a simple copy/paste pgfqkeys for each person's text file that I input.  (I'm trying to find a user-easy method of writing the people's stats in text files, so others can do it also -- so being able to add new stats on the fly by simply adding another "...initial" to the list sounds good.)

@user182238 Ha! indeed. ;) Well, it may or may not be. I think of key-value interfaces as very friendly to use, but they aren't necessarily the most efficient for inputting data. If you have the data in a standard format, why are you doing this manually at all?

I don't have the data in a standard format.  I've got some of this and some of that, and lots of notes that need to be distilled into stats of some sort.  I'm not a programmer and much of the code is beyond me, so I'm looking for something I can understand.  The ability to simply paste values into a pgfqkeys key list, then do a bit of math with some of them, is about as complex as I dare make it.

@user182238 See edit. How about a .new person handler? All this does is set up the path etc. You can define whatever keys you need and then people can just say \pgfkeys{/Joe Bloggs/.new person,/Joe Bloggs/.cd,name=Joe Bloggs,height=... or you could make a simple command to wrap that and make it even simpler.

Sounds promising. I'll have to give your code a try and see whether I can understand how it works. Thanks.  ...  Edit:  I've separated the code into two pgfkeys, one for the initialization and one of the input.  It appears to be working fine.  I still don't understand it all, but it seems to be working with some examples I've plugged in.  Thanks again!

@user182238 I've added an example wrapper, which I think would make this a bit easier to use.]

@user182238 this is not using pgfkeys but seems at least a bit related, maybe it can give you an idea about a possible interface to define new people: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630271/117050

This is no answer for the OP question, but instead an implementation example for the use case described in a comment.
The following doesn't use pgfkeys, but in principle can be implemented in pgfkeys as well. Instead this employs expkv (disclaimer: I'm the author of that package). It is an adaptation of the input syntax implemented in this older answer I wrote: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/630271/117050
The most important adaptation is that this stores the attributes of the people instead of processing them inline. For this I needed to alter the key setting, and to get really concise syntax I dropped the usage of expkv-def for this and used \ekvcsvloop instead, defining the keys with the expkv layer.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\makeatletter
% just to throw an error if \people is already defined. The rest of this uses
% plain TeX syntax to define macros.
\@ifdefinable\people{}

% key setup for different attributes of peoples
\ekvsetdef\people@kv{people}
\protected\def\people#1% temporary definition for a loop
  {\protected\ekvdef{people}{#1}{\people@csset{#1@@\people@name}{##1}}}
% specify a list of available attributes here
\ekvcsvloop\people{name,height,role}

% parser frontend, syntax should be a list of known people in the form
% <key>={<attributes>}, the attribute 'name' will default to '<key>', but can be
% set with a dedicated key as well (in case of name clashes).
\protected\def\people{\ekvparse\people@justname\people@parse}
\def\people@csset#1#2%
  {\expandafter\edef\csname people@#1\endcsname{\unexpanded{#2}}}
\newcommand*\people@name{}
\protected\def\people@justname#1%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#1}{name}
      {\PackageError{people}{Name #1 already defined}{}}%
      {\people@csset{name@@#1}{#1}}%
  }
\protected\def\people@parse#1%
  {%
    \def\people@name{#1}%
    \people@justname{#1}%
    \people@kv
  }

% accessor functions
% check whether attribute #2 of people-key #1 is defined.
\def\ifpeopleattr#1#2{\@ifundefined{people@#2@@#1}\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo}
% get the value of attribute #3 of people-key #2 into macro name #1. If the
% attribute doesn't exist #1 will be \relax.
\protected\def\getpeopleattr#1#2#3%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#2}{#3}
      {\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname people@#3@@#2\endcsname}
      {\let#1\relax}%
  }
% expand to the value of attribute #2 of people-key #1 (wrapped in \unexpanded,
% empty if it doesn't exist)
\def\peopleattr#1#2%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#1}{#2}
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\csname people@#2@@#1\endcsname}%
      }
      {}%
  }
% same as \peopleattr but throws an error on an undefined attribute
\def\requiredpeopleattr#1#2%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#1}{#2}
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\csname people@#2@@#1\endcsname}%
      }%
      {\ekverr{people}{Undefined attribute `#2' for `#1'}}%
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\people
  {
    John,
    Jane = {role = Mrs. Hudson, height=short},
    jane2 = {name = Jane, role = Mary Watson}
  }

\peopleattr{jane2}{name} plays \peopleattr{jane2}{role}.

\peopleattr{John}{name} plays \peopleattr{John}{role}.

\peopleattr{Jane}{name} plays \peopleattr{Jane}{role}.
\end{document}

Result:


Alternative without predefined attributes. Instead everything is allowed.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expkv}

\makeatletter
% just to throw an error if \people is already defined. The rest of this uses
% plain TeX syntax to define macros.
\@ifdefinable\people{}

% parser frontend, syntax should be a list of known people in the form
% <key>={<attributes>}, the attribute 'name' will default to '<key>', but can be
% set with a dedicated key as well (in case of name clashes).
\protected\def\people{\ekvparse\people@justname\people@parse}
\def\people@csset#1#2%
  {\expandafter\edef\csname people@#1\endcsname{\unexpanded{#2}}}
\newcommand*\people@name{}
\protected\def\people@justname#1%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#1}{name}
      {\PackageError{people}{Name #1 already defined}{}}%
      {\people@csset{name@@#1}{#1}}%
  }
\protected\def\people@parse#1%
  {%
    \def\people@name{#1}%
    \people@justname{#1}%
    \ekvparse\people@kv@noval\people@kv
  }
\protected\def\people@kv@noval#1%
  {\PackageError{people}{Missing attribute value for `#1' of `\people@name'}{}}
\protected\def\people@kv#1#2{\people@csset{#1@@\people@name}{#2}}

% accessor functions
% check whether attribute #2 of people-key #1 is defined.
\def\ifpeopleattr#1#2{\@ifundefined{people@#2@@#1}\@secondoftwo\@firstoftwo}
% get the value of attribute #3 of people-key #2 into macro name #1. If the
% attribute doesn't exist #1 will be \relax.
\protected\def\getpeopleattr#1#2#3%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#2}{#3}
      {\expandafter\let\expandafter#1\csname people@#3@@#2\endcsname}
      {\let#1\relax}%
  }
% expand to the value of attribute #2 of people-key #1 (wrapped in \unexpanded,
% empty if it doesn't exist)
\def\peopleattr#1#2%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#1}{#2}
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\csname people@#2@@#1\endcsname}%
      }
      {}%
  }
% same as \peopleattr but throws an error on an undefined attribute
\def\requiredpeopleattr#1#2%
  {%
    \ifpeopleattr{#1}{#2}
      {%
        \unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
          {\csname people@#2@@#1\endcsname}%
      }%
      {\ekverr{people}{Undefined attribute `#2' for `#1'}}%
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\people
  {
    John,
    Jane = {role = Mrs. Hudson, height=short, CoolAttribute=exists},
    jane2 = {name = Jane, role = Mary Watson}
  }

\peopleattr{jane2}{name} plays \peopleattr{jane2}{role}.

\peopleattr{John}{name} plays \peopleattr{John}{role}.

\peopleattr{Jane}{name} plays \peopleattr{Jane}{role}. Also
\peopleattr{Jane}{CoolAttribute}.
\end{document}

Result:

